# Display an XML file as HTML(using XSLT) in iframe

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, iframe

I have a xml file which I receive as a string from the server. I have my own custom XSLT stylesheet which I want to add it to the XML file dynamically. I have a table which has list of xml files so when I click on one of the files, I want to parse the XML string and embed the stylesheet. The issue is when I parse the xml string I get something like this:

```
<book>
 <title>test<title>
</book>
```

with book being the root node. What I was expecting was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
 <title>test<title>
</book>
```

with xml being the root element which then I can access and insert the stylesheet after that. But since it's not the root element and I am not able to add the XSLT stylesheet. Here's what I have tried

```
 const parser = new DOMParser();
 const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'application/xml');
 const result =  xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'href="test.xsl" type="text/xsl"')
 xmlDoc.documentElement.insertAfter(result, xmlDoc.documentElement) // this fails because xml is not the root element
```

Any help is appreciated. Also, if there is an alternative way to handle this problem i'd like that too.

Answer (score 0):

As for the DOM manipulation, I think you want

```
xmlDoc.insertBefore(result, xmlDoc.documentElement);
```

I don't think it will help applying the XSLT, however.

As for the code not working, the following should do:

```js
const xmlString = `<book>
 <title>test<\/title>
</book>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'application/xml');
const result =  xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'href="test.xsl" type="text/xsl"');
xmlDoc.insertBefore(result, xmlDoc.documentElement);

console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc));

console.log(xmlDoc);
```

To process XSLT and write the result to an iframe it might work to use e.g.

```
const xmlString = `<book>
 <title>test<\/title>
</book>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'application/xml');

const xslt = `xslt code goes here`;

const xsltDoc = parser.parseFromString(xsltString, 'application/xml');

const xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();

xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);

const resultDoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);

const iframeDoc = window.frames.frameName.document;

iframeDoc.open();
iframeDoc.write(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc));
iframeDoc.close();
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work because xmlDoc is the root element and you are trying to insert before it.

Comment: @pogbamessi, no idea which error you think you get and why you confuse the document node with the root element but I can assure you that you can insert a processing instruction node before the documentElement child, as shown.

Comment: I was able to insert the XSL stylesheet. But I am not able to render it an iframe. I was trying to do this:  <iframe srcdoc={xmlString.documentElement} title="XML viewer" /> but it gives me [object Element] in the iframe

Comment: @pogbamessi, as I indicated, the task of rendering the result of an XSLT transformation in an iframe can't be solved by inserting a processing instruction into a DOM document. You will need to load the XSLT with XMLHttpRequest, create an XSLTProcesssor, import the stylesheet and use the transformToFragment method to insert or importNode the result into the iframe document or transformToDocument method to serialize and write the result to the iframe.

Comment: const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'application/xml');
  const xsltDoc = parser.parseFromString(xsltString, 'application/xml');

  const xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
  const resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
  console.log(resultDocument);

I keep getting null when i try to do that. I am getting the xml and xslt stylesheet as string from the server.

Comment: I see that when i parse the xslt I get a parse error saying that something is not right with the xslt.

Comment: Please don't expect us to read code you throw into comments, ask a new question with minimal but complete and formatted code samples to allow us to reproduce the problem. Your sample XML in this question is certainly not well-formed so you won't get far if that is your input.